# angular causing an error when I try to put a highcharts div on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, highcharts

I had a controller that looked like this

```
function ChartController($scope, $location, Chart) {
    $scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event) {
        var c = Chart.get({chart_name: $location.hash()}, function(data) {
            $scope.chart = data;
        });
    });
}
```

This displayed the json as expected. I check the `typeof data` which returns an object as expected But when I try to make a div and put it on the page, it gives me an error.

```
function ChartController($scope, $location, Chart) {
    $scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event) {
        var c = Chart.get({chart_name: $location.hash()}, function(data) {
            var chart = $('<div/>').highcharts(data);
            $scope.chart = chart;
        });
    });
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (native)
    at toJson (http://127.0.0.1:5000/pmstats/static/lib/angular/angular.js:762:15)
    at Object.$get.fn (http://127.0.0.1:5000/pmstats/static/lib/angular/angular.js:4981:24)
    at Object.$get.Scope.$digest (http://127.0.0.1:5000/pmstats/static/lib/angular/angular.js:7935:38)
    at Object.$get.Scope.$apply (http://127.0.0.1:5000/pmstats/static/lib/angular/angular.js:8143:24)
    at done (http://127.0.0.1:5000/pmstats/static/lib/angular/angular.js:9170:20)
    at completeRequest (http://127.0.0.1:5000/pmstats/static/lib/angular/angular.js:9333:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (http://127.0.0.1:5000/pmstats/static/lib/angular/angular.js:9303:11) angular.js:5754
(anonymous function) angular.js:5754
$get angular.js:4846
$get.Scope.$digest angular.js:7954
$get.Scope.$apply angular.js:8143
done angular.js:9170
completeRequest angular.js:9333
xhr.onreadystatechange
```

Why is this error being triggered?

Comment: how your json looks like ?